# How can I inspect a function to check for double-underscore usage?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to inspect a function object to know if the function is accessing any double-underscore attributes (e.g., '__name__', '__doc__', etc.).

For a simple function like this:

```
In [11]: def foo(): import math; print(math.__doc__)

In [12]: foo()
This module is always available.  It provides access to the
mathematical functions defined by the C standard.
```

I can look at `LOAD_ATTR` in the disassembly output:

```
In [13]: dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (math) 
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (math) 
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print) 
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (math) 
             18 LOAD_ATTR                2 (__doc__) 
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             24 POP_TOP              
             25 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

Even if the function uses a simple `getattr`, I can parse `dis` output or look at the function code's `co_consts`:

```
In [19]: def foo(): import math; print(getattr(math, '__doc__'))

In [20]: dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (math) 
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (math) 
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print) 
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (getattr) 
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (math) 
             21 LOAD_CONST               2 ('__doc__') 
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             30 POP_TOP              
             31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             34 RETURN_VALUE         

In [21]: foo.__code__.co_consts
Out[21]: (None, 0, '__doc__')
```

But if the function concatenates '_'s, or worse still, uses character or unicodes, then there doesn't appear to be an obvious way to catch these in `dis`, `co_consts` or even in the `ast`.

```
In [22]: def foo(): import math; print(getattr(math, chr(95)*2 + 'doc' + '_' + chr(95)))

In [23]: foo()
This module is always available.  It provides access to the
mathematical functions defined by the C standard.

In [24]: dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (math) 
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (math) 
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print) 
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (getattr) 
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (math) 
             21 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (chr) 
             24 LOAD_CONST               2 (95) 
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             30 LOAD_CONST               3 (2) 
             33 BINARY_MULTIPLY      
             34 LOAD_CONST               4 ('doc') 
             37 BINARY_ADD           
             38 LOAD_CONST               5 ('_') 
             41 BINARY_ADD           
             42 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (chr) 
             45 LOAD_CONST               2 (95) 
             48 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             51 BINARY_ADD           
             52 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             55 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             58 POP_TOP              
             59 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             62 RETURN_VALUE         

In [25]: foo.__code__.co_consts
Out[25]: (None, 0, 95, 2, 'doc', '_')
```

So, is there some way I can be sure of catching all double-underscore access in a function?

Comment: Are we assuming that the functions you're inspecting accept no arguments? Otherwise you could have e.g. `def foo(s): print(getattr(foo, s))` and call `foo('__doc__')`, and I don't think you'd have any way of detecting that.

Comment: I can't make any assumptions about the function, so that's a fair point.  I'd be curious to see if others have suggestions for this scenario.

Comment: I doubt you'll find any way to do this that isn't more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Sadly, I think you may be right. Short of writing a custom getattr (or removing it from the namespace altogether), I can't be sure I'll know of access to "dunder" attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You could always run `pylint` on your code.

As pointed out there are ways around its checks but another option, or possibly in conjunction, would be something along the lines of adding, near the start of the code:

```
oldgetattr = getattr
def getattr(x,y):
    """ No __ access__ """
    assert not y.startswith('__')
    return oldgetattr(x,y)
```

Then run the code - you will probably also need to monkey patch `object.__getattribute__` in a similar manner.

*The above was tested on python 2.7.5+ and seemed to do the job*

```
>>> def foo(): import math; print(getattr(math, chr(95)*2 + 'doc' + '_' + chr(95)))
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in foo
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in getattr
AssertionError
>>>
```

Comment: To check for protected-access (W0212), I presume?  It catches only  math.__doc__ and not getattr(math, '__doc__').  I'll look closely, but I wonder if it's walking the "standard" Python AST, in which case it won't catch getattr type access.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 provides the `__getattribute__` method for total control over access to class instances. This won't solve builtin types, but it will let you detect accesses on your own (passed-in) objects.

Also, you can replace the global variable dictionary with your own, using the CodeObject. So you might extend a dictionary with a getattribute method and insert that as the global namespace. That should give you visibility to global accesses. Then replace global getattr?

See how far that takes you.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, the scope is not limited to my own classes.